# "Missing mapping for field..." at a OneToMany bidirectional relationship

Tags: jpa

I'm really confused with the way a OneToMany biderectional relationship should be implemented in JPA. I'm getting oppossite answers the more I search.

I'm dealing with an scenario where there are users ("Usuario" in spanish), and those users have records("Registro" in spanish). So a user has many records but a record has ony one user.

So here's my code, first the user class:

```
@Entity
@NamedQueries(@NamedQuery(name="Usuario.findAll", query="select o from Usuario o"))
public class Usuario implements Serializable
{
    ...

    @Id
    private String login;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "usuario", cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
    private List<Registro>avances;

    ...
}
```

and the record class:

```
@Entity
@NamedQueries(@NamedQuery(name="Registro.findAll", query="select o from Registro o"))
public class Registro implements  Serializable
{
    ...

    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
    @JoinColumn(name = "usuario_login", referencedColumnName = "login")
    private Usuario usuario;

    ...
}
```

But when I try to add a record to a user I get a long stack trace for this exception:

```
Exception [TOPLINK-45] (Oracle TopLink Essentials - 2.0.1 (Build b09d-fcs (12/06/2007))): oracle.toplink.essentials.exceptions.DescriptorException
Exception Description: Missing mapping for field [USUARIO.login].
Descriptor: RelationalDescriptor(com.teleconsulta.entities.Usuario --> [DatabaseTable(USUARIO)])
    at oracle.toplink.essentials.exceptions.DescriptorException.missingMappingForField(DescriptorException.java:901)
    at oracle.toplink.essentials.internal.descriptors.ObjectBuilder.extractValueFromObjectForField(ObjectBuilder.java:1635)
    ...
```

I have read different opinions saying that the MappedBy should be in the MANY side (records) and others that say that it should be in the ONE side (user). Is this the reason of the problem? how should the MappedBy be put in the many side?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same erro and, in my situation, it was a case sensitive issue.

Wrong:
..., referencedColumnName = "id")

Correct:
..., referencedColumnName = "ID")

Answer (score 0):

To me your entity setup looks fine. The `mappedBy` attribute always belongs to the `ONE`-side, as it references the opposing foreign-key property name which has to be on the `MANY`-side.

This error sounds more like your entity-database mapping is not setup correctly. Are you sure there are db columns in your tables just like your entities' property names? More precisly, if you do not define any column-names (via `@Column`) for your entities' properties, JPA (TOP-LINK) will implicitly try to map these properties to table-columns with the exact same name! So in your case,
is there a table-column named 'login' in your table 'USUARIO'?

Furthermore as you do not use any `ID-Generation Strategy`, there is a chance you just missed to set an appropriate primary key even before persisting your entity.